# What is the most elegant way to hook global variable into JSP (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am very newbie to Spring, so I need a simple advice.
I have a footer which prints today's date. At the moment I use the code:

```
<%@ page import="com.walladverts.helpers.DateHelper" %>
Today is <%=DateHelper.today()%>
```

DateHelper is my class which returns a String, but I know it is not elegant to use scriplets and mixing logic in the view.

What do I need to add as a hook to add the variable to every jsp page in every action in spring?

Comment: Maybe you have more complicated examples to show us, but why not just do `DateHelper.today()` in the controller and add the result to request attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using JSTL.

Use this header

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Get today's date

```
 <jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

And then print it using the formatter

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${today}" dateStyle="long"/>
```

It will print this `April 18, 2013`

Here is the documentation for tag [formatDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html)